# Why isn't our FinderSync extension starting?

Tags: loading, finder, findersync

We have a FinderSync extension for our app. It's been working very well historically. However, sometimes when I'm testing, it doesn't load. It's checked in System Preferences / Extensions, and `pluginkit --match` confirms it's enabled/added:

```
+    com.company.app.Our-Finder-Sync([version number set on build machine])
```

So what's going on? Even without logic behind it and always saying to display a dummy menu for anything within the user root, nothing ever appears in the context menu (and no toolbar button ever appears, despite it having appeared before), and the process never appears in Activity Monitor. There's nothing about it in the Console either.

**Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it in the future?** I suspect it has something to do with uninstalling and reinstalling it more times than macOS likes, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finder just does this sometimes. I'm not sure why, but the easiest workaround I've found is <kbd>⌥</kbd>-clicking the Finder icon in the dock and selecting **Relaunch**.

[image]